# How to modify the voice to Starcraft 1 Terran adjutant's one?

Tags: audio, software-rec, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices

I really like the SC1 Terran Advisor's (adjutant's) voice!

The idea is to modify an audio file of one's speech so that it sounded like adjutant's one. Or, if it is easier, to adjust some automatic voice talker software accordingly.

Maybe there are attempts have been made already. Thanks in advance for reply.

Ubuntu software is preferred.

Comment: To clarify, you're trying to do something similar to what e.g. [Voice Candy](http://www.potionfactory.com/voicecandy) does? This has nothing actually to do with StarCraft, other than that the tool needs to be able to change the voice arbitrarily?

Comment: Exactly. I want to listen to audio books recorded with robot sound. I need a software to adjust the sound more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can settle for your voice to appear more robot-like (not necessarily like adjutant), there are a few options out there

1. A complete procedure using Audacity. https://blog.accusonus.com/voice-changer/robot-voice-changer/
2. A summary of other options. https://itstillworks.com/make-voice-sound-robotic-5446445.html
3. Other options, including Audacity. https://voiceovertip.com/how-to-make-your-voice-sound-like-a-robot/
4. Other options, including Audacity. https://www.reddit.com/r/VoiceActing/comments/b0irum/are_there_any_techniques_to_make_your_voice_sound/

Answer (score 0):

Text to Speech Voice is hard otherwise everything would be talking.

You go with a software package like Ivona produces if you want realistic human voices.

Making your own particular voice package will require a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I see your point. But my task is easier. I want the text to sound **less** realistic. Like a robot voice. There must be some adjustable voice filters.

Comment: Oh, some sort of post speech processing. Yes, that would be far easier.